# JS icons animation

Tags: javascript, performance, html, html5, animation

I've written a simple JS that takes care to animate an icon.

At first I wrote it quickly and without paying attention to any kind of optimization:

```
import '../js/core/sidenav.js';

const SIDENAV_ITEM_USER = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-user');
const SIDENAV_ITEM_SEARCH = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-search');
const SIDENAV_ITEM_ORDER = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-order');
const SIDENAV_ITEM_FILTER = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-filter');

let sidenav_item_icon_angle_user = '0';
let sidenav_item_icon_angle_search = '0';
let sidenav_item_icon_angle_order = '0';
let sidenav_item_icon_angle_filter = '0';

SIDENAV_ITEM_USER.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotate('user');
});

SIDENAV_ITEM_SEARCH.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotate('search');
});

SIDENAV_ITEM_ORDER.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotate('order');
});

SIDENAV_ITEM_FILTER.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotate('filter');
});

function rotate(target) {
  if (target == 'user') {
    var element = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-icon-user');

    if (sidenav_item_icon_angle_user == 0) {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_user = '180';
    } else {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_user = '0';
    }

    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + sidenav_item_icon_angle_user + 'deg)';
  }

  if (target == 'search') {
    var element = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-icon-search');

    if (sidenav_item_icon_angle_search == 0) {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_search = '180';
    } else {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_search = '0';
    }

    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + sidenav_item_icon_angle_search + 'deg)';
  }

  if (target == 'order') {
    var element = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-icon-order');

    if (sidenav_item_icon_angle_order == 0) {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_order = '180';
    } else {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_order = '0';
    }

    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + sidenav_item_icon_angle_order + 'deg)';
  }

  if (target == 'filter') {
    var element = document.getElementById('sidenav-item-icon-filter');

    if (sidenav_item_icon_angle_filter == 0) {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_filter = '180';
    } else {
      sidenav_item_icon_angle_filter = '0';
    }

    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + sidenav_item_icon_angle_filter + 'deg)';
  }
}
```

Subsequently, having verified that the animations work, I have optimized the code:

```
import '../js/core/sidenav.js';

const SIDENAV_CONTENT = document.getElementById('sidenav-content');
const SIDENAV_CONTENT_NODES = SIDENAV_CONTENT.querySelectorAll('a');

var angles = new Map();

SIDENAV_CONTENT_NODES.forEach(function(target) {
  if (target.getAttribute('id').includes('item')) {
    var identifier = target.getAttribute('href').split('-')[3];
    
    angles.set(identifier, '0');

    target.addEventListener('click', function() {
      rotate(identifier);
    });
  }
});

function rotate(target) {
  var element = document.getElementById(`sidenav-item-icon-${target}`);

  angles.get(target) == '0' ? angles.set(target, '180') : angles.set(target, '0');
  element.style.transform = `rotate(${angles.get(target)}deg)`;
}
```

To better understand, this is my HTML:

```
<div id="sidenav-content" class="sidenav-content">
  <div id="sidenav-general-mobile-view">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a id="nav-icon" href="#"><img class="nav-icon" src="../assets/images/nav_cart.svg" height="25">Carrello<span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger nav-badge">5</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card card-user">
          <div class="card-header">
            <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="sidenav-item-user" href="#sidenav-item-body-user" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidenav-item-body-user">
              <img class="icon" src="../assets/images/nav_user.svg" height="25">
              <p class="d-inline mb-0">Accedi</p>
              <img class="arrow" src="../assets/images/sn_general_down.svg" id="sidenav-item-icon-user" height="14" alt="sidenav_item_user_icon">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body collapse" id="sidenav-item-body-user">
            <div class="p-16">
              <ul class="mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a id="nav-signup" href="#">Registrati</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a id="nav-signin" href="#">Accedi</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="sidenav-item-search" href="#sidenav-item-body-search" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidenav-item-body-search">
        <p class="d-inline mb-0">Cerca</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="../assets/images/sn_general_down.svg" id="sidenav-item-icon-search" height="14" alt="sidenav_item_search_icon">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body collapse" id="sidenav-item-body-search">
      <div class="p-16">
        <div class="input-group input-search">
          <span class="input-group-text">
          <img src="../assets/images/input_search.svg" height="14" alt="input-search-icon">
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cerca nel catalogo" aria-label="input-search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="sidenav-item-order" href="#sidenav-item-body-order" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidenav-item-body-order">
        <p class="d-inline mb-0">Ordina</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="../assets/images/sn_general_down.svg" id="sidenav-item-icon-order" height="14" alt="sidenav_item_order_icon">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body collapse" id="sidenav-item-body-order">
      <div class="p-16">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="order-default" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="order-default">Ultimi arrivi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="order-2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="order-2">Prezzo crescente</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="order-3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="order-3">Prezzo decrescente</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-0">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="order-4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="order-4">In promozione</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" id="sidenav-item-filter" href="#sidenav-item-body-filter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidenav-item-body-filter">
        <p class="d-inline mb-0">Filtra</p>
        <img class="arrow" src="../assets/images/sn_general_down.svg" id="sidenav-item-icon-filter" height="14" alt="sidenav_item_filter_icon">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body collapse" id="sidenav-item-body-filter">
      <div class="p-16">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a video on how it works:

[image]

I would like to know if the "optimization" is necessary given the simplicity and length of the code.

Making my considerations:

> **Pro:** *A more streamlined and clean code and the ability to add new elements without having to touch the JS again.*
> **Against:** *Possible increased use of resources due to the use of objects and loops. (?)*

Possibly do you know better ways to optimize this code?

Comment: All that isn't really necessary. It can be done much simpler with one line of CSS: `[aria-expanded="true"] .arrow { transform: rotate(180deg) }`.

Comment: @RoToRa thanks for your comment, I'm new to web development, can you be more detailed?

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/14j9k8he/